Can I create RDLC report for my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app project?
I have created an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web application using Visual Studio 2022. I want to create a report on click of a button which should open in a new tab.
For that, I am trying to use an .RDLC report, but when I go to "Add Item" menu option, I don't see a "Report" option. I have installed required nuget packages and Reporting Services in extension.
Please guide me - is it possible to create a .RDLC report in my case? Or if not, then what are the other ways to create?
Please help me to create a report in correct way using .RDLC report OR any other way.

This question has been asked before. It's currently not supported, however there are workarounds for you by using .Net. Please look for a more detailed answer at this link: Creating RDLC report in ASP.NET Core Web API

We may facing some issue, like Compiler executable file C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v8.0.0\vbc.exe cannot be found.  Here is the workaround. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1467901/integrating-rdlc-reports-in-blazor-web-apps
